# Onedrive for business access shared with me data

Tags: rest, onedrive

I'm using One drive for business. The `/_api/v2.0/drive/view.sharedWithMe` return a folder, and I try to access this folder detail.

I tried several solutions listed [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/working-with-links.htm) but it seems like nothing is working.

When I try to add the folder to the user's drive, I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "message": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
  }
}
```

When I try to "enumerate the content of a shared folder", I got the following one:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "unauthenticated",
    "message": "The caller is not authenticated."
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using shared items and OneDrive for Business, you need a different permission scope. The Files.ReadWrite scope provides access to only the content's of a user's OneDrive for Business. To access shared items, you need to request Sites.ReadWrite.All, which shows up in the Azure Portal as "Read and write items in all site collections". Once you have this scope on your app, and the user has consented to the scope, those calls should work.